# Drawing driving route directions apk isn't running on physical device

Tags: java, android, dictionary, polyline, directions

I am new at Android programming and I have found online some tutorials and codes I am currently trying to run on my device.
One of them happen to be the following code:

-> activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

-> DirectionsJSONParser.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }

    return routes;
    }
    /**
    * Method to decode polyline points
    * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
    * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

-> MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        if(map!=null){

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Setting onclick event listener for the map
            map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Already two locations
                    if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                        markerPoints.clear();
                        map.clear();
                    }

                    // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                    markerPoints.add(point);

                    // Creating MarkerOptions
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                    // Setting the position of the marker
                    options.position(point);

                    /**
                    * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                    * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                    */
                    if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    }

                    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                    map.addMarker(options);

                    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                    if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                        LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                        LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }
    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }`enter code here`
}
```

-> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapnavi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapnavi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapnavi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

this code is supposed to be running on Android 2.3.6 or later but despite my efforts, I cannot get it to run on my phone, running Android 4.3 (since my computer is slow and takes ages to open the emulator). There are no errors, the app is successfully installed and just crashes upon trying to be opened.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong or what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for your time.

Here follows the stack trace:

```
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapnavi/com.example.mapnavi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.example.mapnavi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    ... 11 more
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.F(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.E(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.ju(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
07-16 11:13:19.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17411):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat and we can help you.

Comment: @KarimVarela      Stack trace posted as per your request

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself.

Changed AndroidManifest.xml to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapnavi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapnavi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapnavi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapnavi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_api_key_was_here"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Some elements like the first  tag were missing